# Kubernetes - POD to POD communication over http2

Tags: kubernetes, http2

My code is designed to communicate over Http2. However, when i deploying code which initiates POD to POD call.. It always goes with HTTP1.1

There is no documentation around if http2 protocol would be supported.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-ipvs

I don't want to use external loadbalancer and want POD to POD communication to handle http2.

Is there any way to enable it.

Comment: At a network level, Kubernetes doesn't care: the same Service mechanism is used for any TCP connection, including the text-based HTTP 1, binary HTTP 2, and other protocols like the text-based Redis and binary PostgreSQL wire formats.  Something else is causing your protocol negotiation to fail.

Comment: Is your issue resolved ? Did @David Maze comment help you to resolve the issue??

Comment: No, I tried changing several config, but call was only made via http1.1 for rest api between pods

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your issue as the information provided is not sufficient. In the meantime please have a look into this [document](https://www.tutorialworks.com/kubernetes-pod-communication/)

Comment: We are using Service to communication among Pods. All pods communicate successfully via each other on http1.1 .. when I change my code to use Http2.. it automatically falls back to http1.1.. Seems like "Kind: Service" have some limitation on supporting http2

Comment: http2 works over ssl (https) only. You need to support it in both your application and k8s Service. This maybe the reason.  
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-http2